# jQuery hide & show - overlay image "runs" away before I can click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I'm not sure if this is a jQuery bug or I'm doing something wrong, but here goes.
I have an IMG element with a thumbnail and I want to have a clickable magnifying glass icon (another IMG) show up only when the mouse is hovering over the thumbnail.
This works fine until I move the mouse over to click on the icon. The icon bounces in and out like crazy instead.

```
<link href="Scripts/picpop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/picpop.js"></script>
<div class="bigDiv">
    <img src="images/products/prodmedium/TC-Chelsea-Mushroom2.jpg" alt="" class="smImg">
    <img src="Images/magglass.gif" alt="" class="zImg" data-large-src="images/products/prodlarge/TC-Chelsea-Mushroom2.jpg"  title="Click Here To Zoom"/>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="bigDiv">
    <img src="images/products/prodmedium/TL-AdornCB-Fustic.jpg" alt="" class="smImg">
    <img src="Images/magglass.gif" alt="" class="zImg" data-large-src="images/products/prodlarge/TL-AdornCB-Fustic.jpg" title="Click Here To Zoom" />
</div>
... and so forth ...
```

The jQuery/javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".zImg").click(function () {
    var parentDIV = $(this).parent(); //get the parent container (DIV) for this specific moused-over element
    var bigImg = parentDIV.children(".bigImg"); //now get the child IMG element from the parentDIV (for the large image) that will be or is already created

    // if the large image IMG element does not already exist, create it
    if ($(bigImg).length == 0) {
        var bigImagePath = $(this).attr("data-large-src");
        var newImgElem = $("<img />");
        newImgElem.attr({ "src": bigImagePath, "class": "bigImg", "title": "Click On Image To Close", "onclick": "clearimgsrc(this)" }); //add the attributes and an onclick event 
        newImgElem.appendTo(parentDIV);
    }
});
// strange - the following just goes nuts
$('.smImg').hover(function () {
    var parentDIV = $(this).parent();
    var zImg = parentDIV.children(".zImg");
    $(zImg).show('fast');
}, function () {
    var parentDIV = $(this).parent();
    var zImg = parentDIV.children(".zImg");
    $(zImg).hide('slow');
});

});


function clearimgsrc(elem) {
    $(elem).remove();  // get rid of the IMG tag completely
};
```

The CSS:

```
.smImg
{
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
}

.bigImg
{
    width: 480px;
    height: 480px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: zoom-out;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -350px;
    margin-top: -130px;
    z-index: 200;
}

.zImg
{
    width: 28px;
    height: 44px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: zoom-in;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: -28px;
    margin-top: 176px;
    display: none;
}
```

Changing the delay time has no effect, but it looks like because the z-index of the icon is in front of the thumbnail, that's firing the mouseout event for the underlying thumbnail IMG.  Is there any way to make this work so the icon disappears when you move the mouse away from the thumbnail, but appears long enough to click it?

Here are 2 example links - test2 is w/o the hover, test1 is w/the hover (the crazy one)

[Test2.htm](http://www.miraclecat.com/test2.htm)

[Test1.htm](http://www.miraclecat.com/test1.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the region for this after a long debug

See that you are using  $(.smImg) hover event with mousein & mouseout function

You are adding another image on the top of image with class zImg .

Now when you go on the hover of zImg the hoverout event of smImg is called and hence the zImg bounce back & off.

The solution to this problem is that you have both don't use

```
   $('.smImg').hover
```

smImg event instead of it use  parent div hover event

```
  $('.bigDiv').hover
```

and change your code according to it

Hope this help to trace the logical error

Comment: okay, the bigDiv is the container and hover will fire for everything inside it (which is all 3 images). Maybe wrap the zImg (the magnifier icon) in a DIV?

Comment: the bigDiv w/hover does what I suspected - no go there.
I'm putting up 2 example links on the original edit.

Comment: the issue is with the hover - it is 2 events in one - mouseover and mouseout. I'll try and split it up. I was hoping for someone who had done this before to chime in, but appreciate the help here.

Comment: Ok, I eliminated the need for other hovers (not shown here) and am using the bigDiv hover and changed the CSS so that the DIV is "inline" and the position of the zImg is relative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find()` instead of `.children()`:

```
var parentDIV = ""; //<---decalare vars here
var zImg = "";      // <---and here

$('.smImg').hover(function () {
   parentDIV = $(this).parent();
   zImg = parentDIV.find(".zImg");
   zImg.show('fast');
}, function () {
   zImg.hide('slow');
});
```

and what i think is `$(zImg)` you should not wrap it as a jQuery object it is already a jQuery object so use like this `zImg.show`.

and this too:

```
bigImg.length
```

in the click function.

---

So final code you can use this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var parentDIV = ""; //<---decalare vars here
   var zImg = "";      // <---and here
   $(".zImg").click(function () {
     parentDIV = $(this).parent();
     var bigImg = parentDIV.find(".bigImg");

     // if the large image IMG element does not already exist, create it
     if (bigImg.length == 0) {
        var bigImagePath = $(this).attr("data-large-src");
        var newImgElem = $("<img />");
        newImgElem.attr({ "src": bigImagePath, "class": "bigImg", "title": "Click On Image To Close", "onclick": "clearimgsrc(this)" }); 
        newImgElem.appendTo(parentDIV);
     }
   });

   $('.smImg').hover(function () {
       parentDIV = $(this).parent();
       zImg = parentDIV.find(".zImg");
       zImg.show('fast');
   }, function () {
       parentDIV = $(this).parent();
       zImg = parentDIV.find(".zImg");
       zImg.hide('slow');
   });

});


function clearimgsrc(elem) {
    $(elem).remove();  // get rid of the IMG tag completely
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working, final solution (for those that need it).

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var parentDIV = "";
    var zImg = "";  
    $(".zImg").click(function () {
        parentDIV = $(this).parent();
        var bigImg = parentDIV.find(".bigImg");

        // if the large image IMG element does not already exist, create it
        if (bigImg.length == 0) {
            var bigImagePath = $(this).attr("data-large-src");
            var newImgElem = $("<img />");
            newImgElem.attr({ "src": bigImagePath, "class": "bigImg", "title": "Click On Image To Close", "onclick": "clearimgsrc(this)" });
            newImgElem.appendTo(parentDIV);
        }
    });

    $('.bigDiv').hover(function () {
        zImg = $(this).find(".zImg");
        //zImg.css("visibility", "visible");
        zImg.show('slow');    
    }, function () {
        zImg = $(this).find(".zImg");
        //zImg.css("visibility", "hidden");
        zImg.hide('fast');
    });

});

    function clearimgsrc(elem) {
       $(elem).parent().find(".zImg").hide();
       $(elem).remove();  // get rid of the IMG tag completely
    };
```

The CSS:

```
.bigDiv
{
    display: inline;
}

.smImg
{
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bigImg
{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    width: 480px;
    height: 480px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: zoom-out;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -350px;
    margin-top: -130px;
    z-index: 200;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.zImg
{
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: zoom-in;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -50px;
    display: none;
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
}
```

And HTML:

```
<link href="Scripts/picpop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/picpop.js"></script>
<div class="bigDiv">
    <img src="images/products/prodmedium/TC-Chelsea-Mushroom2.jpg" alt="" class="smImg">
    <img src="Images/MagIconPlus1smT.png" alt="" class="zImg" data-large-src="images/products/prodlarge/TC-Chelsea-Mushroom2.jpg"  title="Click Here To Zoom"/>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="bigDiv">
    <img src="images/products/prodmedium/TL-AdornCB-Fustic.jpg" alt="" class="smImg">
    <img src="Images/MagIconPlus1smT.png" alt="" class="zImg" data-large-src="images/products/prodlarge/TL-AdornCB-Fustic.jpg" title="Click Here To Zoom" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps others besides me (total noob to jQuery)